# Regex for avoid first more than one zero

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

i want to regex that match the following case: it will be used for input field as pattern;

case:

```
1. 000   //not match
2. 100.000  //match
3. 0         //match
4. 0.0    //match
5. 0.01   //match
6. 00100   // not match    
7. 001.1   //not match
8. 101   // match 
9. 0.0.01 //not match
10. 02001 // not match
```

i try with `[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?`

i will use in the input field as pattern. please help me.

```html
<input type="text"  required="" pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?"  name="bstatus[bstatus_amount][]">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate with a lookahead that asserts the absence of zero leading digits, and duplicate dots:

```regex
^(?!0\d|[^.]*\.[^.]*\.)\d+(\.\d\d?)?
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/wB0eM1/4).

Though considering your use case, what you need is simply:

```regex
^(?!0\d|[^.]*\.[^.]*\.)\d
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/wB0eM1/5).

```
echo preg_match('/^(?!0\d|[^.]*\.[^.]*\.)\d/', $str);
```

Answer (score -2):

Very simple solution is:

```regex
/^00/
```

`preg_match` will return `true` for invalid strings.

Comment: Did you check this code before posting?
It does not match a single of the given cases.
See here http://regex101.com/r/oG7tW2/1

Comment: Title of question is "Regex for avoid first more than one zero" - my regex looks for two ZEROS on string begin.

Comment: It's not the best approach to match with this regex and invert the result, considering then empty strings will be considered valid as well.